# old phone contacts and e mail

Tags: google-backup

I had a android phone a while back an i sync it to my gmail so i could save contacts.but being its been so long and i'm not sure of the g mail account will i still have the contacts there if i can remember or find the right gmail account and will i be able to move them to my new phone even though i'm with a new company? i tried contacting old cell company to ask them for help and still no reply.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. If your contacts were successfully synced with your Google Account you can easily move them to your new phone using the same Google Account. Any Android phone from any company can be used to restore the accounts synced with your Google Account.